# Is there a way to make Xcode handle brackets more intelligently?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode, if you are calling a method that takes a series of flags as an argument, when you type the right bracket character, it creates a new left bracket at the last flag, rather than at the start of the line. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    // Type this...
    someFunc withFlags:FlagA|FlagB|FlagC

    // Now type a right bracket ]
    someFunc withFlags:FlagA|FlagB|[FlagC ]

    // It should be this:
    [someFunc withFlags:FlagA|FlagB|FlagC]
```

Comment: Very annoying, I agree.

Comment: Yes: [file a bug!](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: FYI: Filed a bug with Apple: 15713698

Comment: Version is 5.0 (5A1412). For some reason I haven't received the update through the App Store. I'll update manually and report back.

Comment: Now on 5.0.2 (5A3005). Problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

Turn-On **Xcode->Preferences->TextEditing->Editing->Automatically balance brackets in ObjectiveC method calls**

I'm using Xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005). The below both of them worked fine for me.It automatically created left bracket when I closed the right one.

```
 [self someFunc:1 Flag:YES|YES|YES];
 [self someFunc:YES|YES|YES];

- (void)someFunc:(int)x Flag:(BOOL)yes
{

}
- (void)someFunc:(BOOL)yes
{

}
```

Here is my Xcode settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, unfortunately. Although, filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple will make this more likely to get fixed.  If this behavior breaks your [flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29), you can always turn it off in the settings. Xcode -> Preferences... -> Text Editing -> "Automatically insert closing braces ('}')"

Answer (score 0):

Type the first bracket when you start the line. 
That is what you should do first. 
Also you should use parentheses around your flags.

Comment: Why should there be parentheses around the flags?

Comment: Legibility really. Indicating they are one thing. I tend to try to make things explicit visually. I know it doesn't change the compilation. You can see the same in Apple code.  this also helps Xcode know the scope when you type the closing bracket but did not type the first bracket.

Comment: Another thing I think about with parenthesis as a habit is that you can avoid weird operator precedence issues in general when you make that a habit. C